# python using @ method to substitute a value

Tags: python, pandas, variables, methods

How do I use the @ method / environment variable in python? In order to substitute @var with the value defined previously in the sentence var= ?

```
var= 'column1'
df.groupby('@var').count().unstack().ID.plot(kind='bar');
plt.title(@var)
```

Comment: am I missing something? Why not just `df.groupby(var)`. The `@` is required for things like eval/query which automatically assume names respond to the columns not a static variable.

Comment: because I have a large list of different columns, but I don't need to run into a loop, I want to randomly access to a variable specifying it at the beginning, and leaving the rest of the code invariate

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary like `vars = {'var': 'column1'}` and then use it like `df.groupby(vars['var'])`